# python cx_Oracle datetime error

Tags: python, cx-oracle

I have Python 3.7 and cx_Oracle 6.4.1 and I am having an issue with querying datetimes.

For example, if I query for "select sysdate from dual"
I get "ValueError: hour must be in 0..23

However, if I query "select to_char(sysdate, 'YYYY-MM-DD') from dual"
I don't have any issues.

I didn't have this issue when I was on Python 3.6.3 and cx_Oracle 6.0.2

Edit:
Not much code, I am just including the minimum amount needed to reproduce.

```
>>> DB = cx_Oracle.connect(uid,pwd,DSN)
>>> cursor = DB.cursor()
>>> cursor.execute("select sysdate from dual")
>>> [r for r in cursor]

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <listcomp>
ValueError: hour must be in 0..23

>>> cursor.execute("select to_char(sysdate, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24-MI-SS') from dual")
>>> [r for r in cursor]
[('2018-08-20 10-53-04',)]
```

Also, I forgot to mention that I am using Windows 10.

Comment: That query works just fine for me. Can you provide the complete code that you are running that is failing?

Comment: I can reproduce this while running python3.7-slim and cx_Oracle 7.0.0 or 6.4.1; had to revert to python3.5-slim, which seems to work with either version of cx_Oracle listed above